# Object of class Dollar could not be converted to int

Tags: php

I was going through the book named "Test-Driven Development By Example" By the author Kent Beck.

I am trying to write a similar function in php but not understanding the steps.

Original function:

Test function:

```
public void testEquality() {
    assertTrue(new Dollar(5).equals(new Dollar(5)));
    assertFalse(new Dollar(5).equals(new Dollar(6)));
}
```

Class function:

```
public boolean equals(Object object) {
   Dollar dollar = (Dollar) object;
   return amount == dollar.amount;
}
```

My code:

Test function:

```
public function setup() {
   $this->dollarFive = new Dollar(5);
}

public function testEquality() {
    $this->assertTrue($this->dollarFive->equals(new Dollar(5)));
}
```

Class Function:

```
class Dollar
{   
  public function __construct($amount) {
    $this->amount = (int) $amount;
  }

   public function equals(Dollar $object) {
     $this->Object = $object;
     return $this->amount == $this->Object;
   }    
}
```

While executing the test case i am getting the following error.

> Object of class Dollar could not be converted to int

Need some help on this. How can i fix this?

Comment: What is `$this->Object = $object;` good for?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
return $this->amount == $this->Object;
```

`$this->amount` is an int, `$this->Object` isn't an int. You tried to compare each other, thus you'll get

> Object of class Dollar could not be converted to int

You probably mean

```
return $this->amount == $this->Object->amount;
```

However, there is also something curious in your class

```
class Dollar {
  public $amount = 0; // <-- forgotten
  public function __construct($amount) {
    $this->amount = (int) $amount;
  }

   public function equals(Dollar $object) {
     $this->Object = $object; // <--- ?!?
     return $this->amount == $this->Object;
   }    
}
```

you'll probably want just

```
   public function equals(Dollar $object) {
     return $this->amount == $object->amount;
   }
```